# Jquery multiple dynamic progress bars

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am a couple instances of Jquery UI progress bar widget on my page.

The problem I'm having is that it only loads the first value, and mimics each for each bar instead of cycling through all the bars on the page and getting unique values.  can anyone explain why the each function is not looping through the values correctly?

Added a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Uy9cA/25/

```
<div class="progress_bar" value="20"><div class="progress-label">Loading...</div></div> <div class="progress_bar" value="40"><div class="progress-label">Loading...</div></div>
```

### Jquery

```
  $(function() {  
  $('.progress_bar').each(function() {
        var progressbar = $( ".progress_bar" ),
        progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" ),
        progressvalue = $(".progress_bar").attr('value');
        console.log(progressvalue);  

        progressbar.progressbar({
        value: false,
        change: function() {
        progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "% Complete" );
        },
        complete: function() {
        progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
       }
       });

      function progress() {        
      var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;

       progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 )
      .removeClass("beginning middle end")
      .addClass(val < 40 ? "beginning" : val < 80 ? "middle" : "end");

      if ( val < progressvalue ) 
      {
        setTimeout( progress, 100 );
       }
      }

    setTimeout( progress, 100 );
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this:  **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy9cA/27/)**

Use:

```
  var progressbar = $(this),
    progressLabel = $(this).find( ".progress-label" ),
    progressvalue = $(this).attr('value');
```

instead of:

```
 var progressbar = $( ".progress_bar" ),
    progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" ),
    progressvalue = $(".progress_bar").attr('value');
```

For each `.progress_bar` class you have to get its own properties/children using `$(this)`

Comment: This is correct. Your references to your progress bars are currently incorrect. Using $(this) will fix it.

Comment: Arg, you are correct I forgot i needed a reference to each individual class instance inside the each loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've given them all the same class name. You need to have a way of referring to them independently. Give them different class names, or an additional class name or an id or something. For example:

```
<div class="progress_bar bar1" value ="80"><div class="progress-label barlabel1">Loading...</div></div>
<div class="progress_bar bar2" value="20"><div class="progress-label barlabel2">Loading...</div></div>
<div class="progress_bar bar3" value="40"><div class="progress-label barlabel3">Loading...</div></div>
```

Then adjust your code to deal with each individually.